# Julia syntax: "..." expression outside call around

Tags: julia

Given this data:

```
data   = ["red", "blue", "green"]
counts = [2000, 2000, 1]
```

Why can I do

```
[fill("red", 2000)..., fill("blue", 2000)..., fill("green", 1)...]
```

but not

```
[fill(data[i], counts[i])... for i in 1:3]
syntax: "..." expression outside call around
```

P.s.

I know this is possible, it just doesn't feel very elegant:

```
cat([fill(data[i], counts[i]) for i in 1:3]..., dims=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says `...` is allowed is only in a function call, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#...-splits-one-argument-into-many-different-arguments-in-function-calls.

However, note that you can do e.g.:

```
reduce(vcat, fill(data[i], counts[i]) for i in 1:3)
```

(this unnecessarily allocates with `fill` but is relatively short to write)

Comment: I understood that the problem was that a list comprehension isn't a function call. I just don 'tunderstand why `[fill("red", 2000)..., <etc.>]` is, but a list comprehension isn't. That doesn't feel consistent to me.

Comment: `[fill("red", 2000)..., <etc.>]` is just a syntactic sugar for a function call `vcat(fill("red", 2000)..., <etc.>)` (it gets rewritten to the second form before execution).